# Incompatible pointer types sending 'Class' to parameter of type 'id<UIActionSheetDelegate>'

Tags: ios, warnings, incompatibility

I am receiving the warning Incompatible pointer types sending 'Class' to parameter of type 'id' in the line "delegate:self" below:

```
    + (SHKActionSheet *)actionSheetForType:(SHKShareType)type
{
    SHKActionSheet *as = [[SHKActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:SHKLocalizedString(@"Share")
                                                      delegate:self
                                             cancelButtonTitle:nil
                                        destructiveButtonTitle:nil
                                             otherButtonTitles:nil];
    as.item = [[[SHKItem alloc] init] autorelease];
    as.item.shareType = type;
```

This warning is in ShareKit, if anyone knows how to fix it, please let me know!

Comment: It is a static method, delegate methods usually call for instance methods.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You are trying to pass self parameter in a static method. It is not right as there is no particular instance of this object in static methods. Make it either non static method or pass some instance of this class as delegate.

Comment: How would I pass an instance of the class as delegate? Do you have ShareKit, did you fix this warning?

Comment: You see you has a + near your method. This mean that it is static method and can be called without specifying particular instance of the class but just calling directly method of your class in a form [MyClass method]; Is it answers your question?

Comment: It needs to be a + method though, otherwise it will break the feature

Comment: In this case you need to initialize an instance of a class in a way [[MyClass] alloc] initSomething]; retain it, store it in a static variable to avoid unexpected dealloc and pass as delegate. At the same time you will need to care of proper releasing of this instance when time will come.

Answer (score 9):

When working with a static Class, you can manually get ride of the warning:

```
delegate:(id<UIActionSheetDelegate>)self
```

Answer (score 3):

Try using nil instead of self (xcode 4.2 iOS 5).